# LINQ2SQL switch to EF on reading a list of records

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, csla

I am trying to switch from LINQ2SQL to EF ... I am getting the following error with some code that originally worked with LINQ2SQL and seems to compile correctly:

> Csla.DataPortalException:
>   DataPortal.Fetch failed (LINQ to
>   Entities does not recognize the method
>   'MyApp.Logic.UserInfo
>   FetchUserInfo(MyApp.Data.User)'
>   method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.)
>
> ---> Csla.Reflection.CallMethodException:
>   DataPortal_Fetch method call failed
>
> ---> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'MyApp.Logic.UserInfo
>   FetchUserInfo(MyApp.Data.User)'
>   method, and this method cannot be
>   translat...

This is the code:

```
var data = query.Select(row => UserInfo.FetchUserInfo(row));

this.AddRange(data);
```

I'm trying to read a list of data and load the entities into my class. I'm new to EF and just think I am overlooking something.

Any help would be appreciated!

For those interested, **the solution** was:

```
var data = query.AsEnumerable().Select(UserInfo.FetchUserInfo);
```

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of this `FetchUserInfo` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see the problem is that Linq to Entities provider knows nothing about how to translate you custom method `FetchUserInfo` to ESQL.

If `UserInfo` is just a DTO and `UserInfo.FetchUserInfo` is a kind of Entity to DTO conversion method this would help

```
var data = query.AsEnumerable().Select(row => UserInfo.FetchUserInfo(row));
```

`.AsEnumerable()` invoke will result in materialization of `query` results to memory objects.

Comment: That was the trick! I knew I was missing something simple ... thank you!